# Imodeljs - How are the tiles are getting created in IModelJs?How root tile is created in imodelJs?

Tags: javascript, tile, cesiumjs, imodeljs

Geometric elements to create the tiles but exact flow of tile creation is not known yet.
How root tile is created in imodelJs ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. THe question is not ery clear. Please consider [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do you need help with a particular code? If you want deeper insights into *how* the tiles are created, you may want to [look into the code](https://github.com/imodeljs/simple-viewer-app) of imodelJs.

Answer (score 1):

Tiles are created by the imodeljs-native package that is bundled with imodeljs-backend. This package is written in C++ and is the only non-open source iModel.js package. Given a model, a tile volume, and a desired level of detail, geometric elements within the model and intersecting the volume are converted to meshes and polylines at the requested level of detail. The exact process is quite involved and constantly evolving as new features and performance optimizations are implemented.